# Xlabel on chaco plot without creating new axis

Tags: python, plot, chaco

I have a Chaco ToolBarPlot and simply want to set the xlabel to "Wavelength".  In matplotlib, obviously it would be:

```
plt.xlabel('Wavelength')
```

In Chaco, I thought it would be (from within the class):

```
self.plot.index_axis.label = 'Wavelength'
```

But all of the examples I can find build a new axis object entirely.  For example:

`label_axis = LabelAxis(plot, orientation='bottom', ...)
plot.index_axis = label_axis`

This seems like overkill...  Is it possible to set the axis label without creating a new axis?  Part of the reason it's a pain is that I have to change this trait dynamically, and it can take on a lot of different values depending on what the user is doing in the UI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC the desired attribute is `title` not `label`. See:
http://docs.enthought.com/chaco/user_manual/basic_elements/overlays.html#overlays-axis-legend-grid-etc
http://osdir.com/ml/python-enthought-devel/2009-09/msg00204.html